# Cannot change width and number of stars of RatingBar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, rating, ratingbar

I am trying to set a `RatingBar` with only 5 stars but it expands to fill the width of the screen.

I have found similar problems:

- [How to make RatingBar to show five stars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858600/how-to-make-ratingbar-to-show-five-stars/10819710)
- [Android RatingBar - a complete mess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454644/android-ratingbar-a-complete-mess?rq=1)
- [android rating bar xml and numStars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724376/android-rating-bar-xml-and-numstars?rq=1)

However, most of the time the solution is to set the width to `wrap_content` but the width for me has always been `wrap_content`.

This is my layout. If you scroll right to the bottom you'll see the two `RatingBar`s:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/add_spot_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shrinkColumns="1"
        android:stretchColumns="1" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2sp" >

            <TextView android:text="Distance:" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/distancePopup" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2sp" >

            <TextView android:text="Address:" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/addrPopup" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2sp" >

            <TextView android:text="Type:" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/typePopup" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2sp" >

            <TextView android:text="Terrain:" />

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/terrainPopup"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:isIndicator="true"
                android:max="5"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:stepSize="1" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView android:text="Difficulty:" />

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/difficultyPopup"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:isIndicator="true"
                android:max="5"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:stepSize="0.1" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2sp" >

            <TextView android:text="Description:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/descPopup"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:lines="2"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: is it solved for you?

Answer (score 3):

I think this can be solved nesting the RATINGBAR inside a RELATIVELAYOUT. I think this problem is because the nature of TableLayout is to fill the parent in any case and RATINGBAR takes the width of the parent. So I solved this nesting the RATINGBAR inside a RELATIVELAYOUT and setting LAYOUT_WIDTH and LAYOUT_HEIGT on WRAP_CONTENT for both (RATINGBAR and RELATIVE LAYOUT). Only in this case I was able to have a RATINGBAR inside a TABLELAYOUT.

Hope helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

For future Googlers,

The answer by Amit helped me with the problem : The rating widget was showing way too many stars.

This is because the widget HAS to be set to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` for numstars to be taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

Use Relative Layout as parent of rating bar 
and wrap_content for rating bar will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

In Table Layout you are using like

```
    android:shrinkColumns="1"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
```

Here you shrinking and streching the same column number.

I removed the

```
android:stretchColumns="1"
```

And the its working for me.

[image]

Final layout

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/add_spot_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shrinkColumns="1" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp" >

        <TextView android:text="Distance:" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/distancePopup" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp" >

        <TextView android:text="Address:" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/addrPopup" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp" >

        <TextView android:text="Type:" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/typePopup" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp" >

        <TextView android:text="Terrain:" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/terrainPopup"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:max="5"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:stepSize="1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView android:text="Difficulty:" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/difficultyPopup"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:max="5"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:stepSize="0.1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp" >

        <TextView android:text="Description:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descPopup"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:lines="2"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```